# add2home.js on iOS6 does not close when user taps the x button

Tags: javascript, ios

I am using this [script](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) to show mobile users how to add their website to the homescreen. It works as it should on an iPhone with iOS 5, but on iOS 6 the bubble does not fade out when the user clicks the `[X]` in the top right corner. It DOES fade out when the timeout has been reached (about 8-10 seconds).

The demo on the website has this problem, too.

JS and CSS source [here](https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I found out it was to do with when my iphone 4s had private browsing switched to on. Apparently in private browsing mode safari throws a localStorage error.

There is a solution here. It worked for me: https://github.com/gdub22/add-to-homescreen/blob/845d5a5d3ceb0c7601a90b1fe31fc271670f9e58/src/add2home.js